# Fn+F10, Side arrow keys (right and left) and Ctrl don't work

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Hi my name is not important but I have a K450J Asus Laptop and I would like to troubleshoot closer.
I recently installed XUbuntu (I had the same problems with Ubuntu), formatted my disk and still have the problem; Took my computer to the store and the keyboard is all good, so something in Linux is messing with my keyboard but I don't know what it is. Would like your help.

Oh and yeah i already did check the keyboard response with `xev`
and... no event from  <kbd>Fn</kbd>  +  <kbd>F10</kbd> , neither individually from both, no event either from  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  and side arrow keys.

Please I need your help.